# Microsoft Access 2002 Package Deployment Problem

Tags: ms-access, deployment, package

I've created a split Access database application and used the packaging wizard to create a deployment package.  All the files are installed by the deployment package into C:\Documemts and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Provision Manager, this is too avoid Windows Vista not allowing write access to the Program Files directory.

The application installs OK on both Vista and XP and creates a Provision Manager entry in the Program Group in the user account that installed the application, however when I login using another account (both Admin and non-admin ones) the there is no Provision Manager item listed in the Program Group.

Can anyone enlighten me as to what is going on here and more importantly how I can ensure that the deployment package creates a Program Group item for each user account.

Thanks

Marc

Answer (score 0):

To ENSURE that the package has created the right Program Group, look in All Users/Start Menu/Programs because these programs are automatically placed in every user's Start Menu when they log in. Similar for Desktop shortcuts, place them in All Users/Desktop

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem (and it's not really a problem but a *feature*) is that MS tightened up security in Windows Vista.   Users are no longer allowed to update the All Users Start Menu/Programs or Application Data folder.   Only administrators can update such as using instllers.   Now that's mostly fine for the shortcuts to Access FEs.  The real problem arises with the FE MDB/MDEs as users pretty much have to have read/write/create/delete (although strictly speaking create/delete privilieges are only required for LDB files.)  So those can't be installed into the All Users folders.

The solution is to split the runtime install into two components.  The administrator types install the actual Access runtime into Program Files along with msaccess.exe , etc, etc.

Then you have a second install with the users can run which puts the Access FE MDB/MDE, and other files in the Current Users Applications Data folder along with shortcuts on the desktop.

If the users are on your local LAN you could use the free [Auto FE Updater](http://www.autofeupdater.com) utility to handle the FE installation for users.

If the users are remote then you can use the  Sample inno script which checks to see if a version of Access is installed.  If not it tells you to install a runtime version of Access.  If installed then it continues to install your FE MDE and other assorted files.
http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.access/msg/10e3fc9234660872?hl=en

[Sample inno script which "wraps" the package wizard install into a single .exe](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.databases.ms-access/msg/4aa1b33a191bf1f8?hl=en)

[Deploying updates to your software in a Runtime environment for Access 2007](http://www.members.shaw.ca/AlbertKallal/RunTime/InstallExample.htm)